# How to write output to a dynamic path using Apache Beam Python

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, apache-beam, dataflow

I'm very new at apache beam. My scenario is like below,

I have multiple events which in json format. In each event, event_time column indicates that event's create time and I'm calculating their create date using event_time.
I want to write this events under their date partitions seperately. My code is like

```
import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.io import WriteToText
from apache_beam.pvalue import TaggedOutput
import json
import time


class EventFormatter(beam.DoFn):

  def process(self, element, *args, **kwargs):
    tmp_dict = {}
    for i in range(len(element['properties'])):
        tmp_dict['messageid'] = element['messageid']
        tmp_dict['userid'] = element['userid']
        tmp_dict['event_time'] = element['event_time']
        tmp_dict['productid'] = element['properties'][i]['productid']

        yield tmp_dict


class DateParser(beam.DoFn):

    def process(self, element, *args, **kwargs):
        key = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d', time.localtime(element.get('event_time')))
        print(key, element)
        yield TaggedOutput(time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d', time.localtime(element.get('event_time'))), element)


with beam.Pipeline() as pipeline:
  events = (
      pipeline
      | 'Sample Events' >> beam.Create([
          {"messageid": "6b1291ea-e50d-425b-9940-44c2aff089c1", "userid": "user-78", "event_time": 1598516997, "properties": [{"productid": "product-173"}]},
          {"messageid": "b8b14eb3-8e39-42a3-9528-a323b10a7686", "userid": "user-74", "event_time": 1598346837, "properties": [{"productid": "product-143"},{"productid": "product-144"}]}
        ])
      | beam.ParDo(EventFormatter())
      | beam.ParDo(DateParser())
  )


  output = events | "Parse Date" >> WriteToText('/Users/oguz.aydin/Desktop/event_folder/date={}/'.format(....))
```

I'm not able to find how i should complete the format block. When I run code to print result, it gives

```
('2020-08-27', {'productid': 'product-173', 'userid': 'user-78', 'event_time': 1598516997, 'messageid': '6b1291ea-e50d-425b-9940-44c2aff089c1'})
('2020-08-25', {'productid': 'product-143', 'userid': 'user-74', 'event_time': 1598346837, 'messageid': 'b8b14eb3-8e39-42a3-9528-a323b10a7686'})
('2020-08-25', {'productid': 'product-144', 'userid': 'user-74', 'event_time': 1598346837, 'messageid': 'b8b14eb3-8e39-42a3-9528-a323b10a7686'})
```

as example. I want to write 2 events under the date=2020-08-25 folder and other one date=2020-08-27.

At the end of the day I want to write each event under their create date folder.

How can i do this?

Thanks for your help,

Oguz.

Answer (score 3):

Concretely, to write several elements per key, you can do something like

```
class WriteByKey(apache_beam.DoFn):
    def process(self, kvs):
         # All values with the same key will come in at once.
         key, values = kvs
         with beam.io.gcp.gcsio.GcsIO().open(f'gs://bucket/path/{key}.extension', 'w') as fp:
             for value in values:
                 fp.write(value)
                 fp.write('\n')

with beam.Pipeline() as pipeline:
  events = (
      pipeline
      | ...
      | beam.ParDo(EventFormatter())
      | beam.ParDo(DateParser())
  )
  output = events | beam.GroupByKey() | beam.ParDo(WriteByKey())
```

Note that runners may need to retry elements on failure, so instead of writing directly to the output a safer approach would be to write to a temporary file and then atomically rename it on success, e.g.

```
class WriteByKey(apache_beam.DoFn):
    def process(self, kvs):
         # All values with the same key will come in at once.
         key, values = kvs
         nonce = random.randint(1, 1e9)
         path = f'gs://bucket/path/{key}.extension'
         temp_path = f'{path}-{nonce}'
         with beam.io.gcp.gcsio.GcsIO().open(temp_path, 'w') as fp:
             for value in values:
                 fp.write(value)
                 fp.write('\n')
         beam.io.gcp.gcsio.GcsIO().rename(temp_path, path)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, works well! (strings need to be encoded before calling .write)

Answer (score 2):

In your code, you're using multiple outputs.
This is meant to connect the output of a DoFn (a ParDo) to another DoFn and this is **static** for the whole pipeline.

If you want to dump data into different files based on the content of you have, you must implement a DoFn just for writing.

Something like this:

```
class WriteByKey(apache_beam.DoFn):
   def process(self, kv):
        key, value = kv
        with beam.io.gcp.gcsio.GcsIO().open(f'gs://bucket/path/{key}.extension', 'a') as fp:
            fp.write(value)
```

You should change your DataParser DoFn to yield a tuple (date, value) instead of a TaggedOut, and change the pipeline to something like this:

```
with beam.Pipeline() as pipeline:
  events = (
      pipeline
      | 'Sample Events' >> beam.Create([
          {"messageid": "6b1291ea-e50d-425b-9940-44c2aff089c1", "userid": "user-78", "event_time": 1598516997, "properties": [{"productid": "product-173"}]},
          {"messageid": "b8b14eb3-8e39-42a3-9528-a323b10a7686", "userid": "user-74", "event_time": 1598346837, "properties": [{"productid": "product-143"},{"productid": "product-144"}]}
        ])
      | beam.ParDo(EventFormatter())
      | beam.ParDo(DateParser()) | beam.ParDo(WriteByKey())
  )
```

Comment: thanks for your answer Iñigo, but i have a problem with your solution. In WriteByKey class, there is no append mode in beam.io.gcp.gcsio.GcsIO().open so I overwrite my events while writing. I can produce multiple file for each event but it is unproductive approach. Can you suggest another solution to handle this?

Comment: Yes, it throws an exception id thw file already exists.The best option is to add another step in the pipeline with beam.GroupByKey() [see example](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/transforms/python/aggregation/groupbykey/)